# IF text in column = something; INDEX - MATCH using specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following working formula in column D (EntityId).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('MMA Product List'!$A:$A,MATCH(E2, 'MMA Product List'!$B:$B,0)), "Not Found")
```

It grabs the ID from the *MMA Product List* sheet if the name in column E (Entity Name) is a match.

*MMA Uploader* sheet:
[image]

*MMA Product List* sheet:
[image]

Since both sheets have the *Baja Turkey Avocado Sandwich* name, it will return the ID from column A *MMA Product List* sheet to column D *EntityId*.

How can I make my formula dependent on the EntityType in column C?

For example,
IF column C EntityType is *Products*, grab the ID from the *MMA Products List* sheet.
IF column C EntityType is *Ingredient*, grab the ID from the *Ingredients List* sheet.
IF column C EntityType is *MenuCategory*, grab the ID from the *Menu Category* sheet.

How can I implement an IF statement in that formula?

Answer (score 1):

In your formula where you feed range for INDEX & MATCH you can put an IF statement wrapped in INDIRECT formula e.g.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Table"&IF(C2="MenuCategory",1,IF(C2="Products",2,IF(C2="Ingredient",3,FALSE)))&"[id]"),MATCH(E2,INDIRECT("Table"&IF(C2="MenuCategory",1,IF(C2="Products",2,IF(C2="Ingredient",3,FALSE)))&"[name]"),0)), "Not Found")
```

So in my example I created three tables (called Table1, Table2, Table3) with different IDs and then depending on value in C2 INDIRECT serves required range.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @tomi09pl, the solution that worked best for me has been added to this question. This was very helpful as well!

Answer (score 0):

tomi09pl posted a great solution, but I decided the method below works best for my case:

```
=IF(C2="Products", IFERROR(INDEX('MMA Product List'!$A:$A,MATCH(E2, 'MMA Product List'!$B:$B,0)), "Not Found"), IF(C2="MenuCategory", IFERROR(INDEX('Products Category List'!$B:$B,MATCH(E2, 'Products Category List'!$A:$A,0)), "Not Found"), IF(C2="Ingredient", IFERROR(INDEX('Ingredients List'!$A:$A,MATCH(E2, 'Ingredients List'!$B:$B,0)), "Not Found"), "Not Found")))
```

Thanks to all.